# dropdown menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

does anyone know why this isn't working? i think just the b2 field inside the jquery function is actually reading what the user types in the text field, but it doesn't read at all the chosen option on the dropdown menu

```
<input type="hidden">
<select name='dropdown' size=1 id='category' name='cat'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>"
  <option value='2'>3</option>
</select>
<p> 
  Details:<br>
  <input type='text' rows='4' cols='50' id='content' /><br>
  <button class='submitreport'>Submit</button>
</p>



<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(function() {
    $('.submitreport').live('click', 'button', function() {
      a1 = $(this).val();
      a2=$(this).prev().val();
      b1=$(this).prev().prev().val();
      b2=$(this).prev().prev().prev().val();
      b3=$(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().val();
      b4=$(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().val();
      b5=$(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().val();
      b6=$(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().val();
      my_data={
        'a1':a1,
        'a2':a2,
        'b1':b1,
        'b2':b2,
        'b2':b2,
        'b3':b3,
        'b4':b4,
        'b5':b5,
        'b5':b5,
        'b6':b6
      };
      console.log(my_data);
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, I'd recommend switching to `click()`

```
$('.submitreport').click(function() {
  // code to be executed on click
});
```

Additionally, `.prev()` in your code would be the previous element, the `<br />` tag.